# Strangest Array Exception Ever in VSC - Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, dll, initialization

I'm experiencing the wierdest excpetion ever!

So, I'm learning all about arrays in c#, (coding in VSC), and whenever I initialise an array with more than 2 elements, I get an 'Unexpected Exception'. Apart from this, my antivirus (Kaspersky) also deletes my .dll file (Giraffe.dll). However, when I initialise an array with only 1 or 2 elements, it works perfectly fine. Note that this only happens when I initialise the array myself directly, in the same line of declaration, and not initialising it through user input and a for loop. The excpetion occured in my 'Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets' file and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO6XX.png)

If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Below, I've attached some images to further explain the problem.

[The error detected in the 'Problems' section in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHFzP.png)

[The error detected in the 'Terminal' section in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhpYE.png)

[The error in the Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets' file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKe32.png)

[Karpersky deleting my .dll file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QumUp.png)

I tried creating an exception of the file 'Giraffe' in my antivirus so as to prevent it from deleting my .dll file. I also tried creating an exception of the 'Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets' file. However, these 2 exceptions had no effect on the compilation error I was experiencing.

Furthermore, I tried deleting the project (Giraffe) and creating it from scratch to make sure that the error was occuring because of that array.

Apart from this, I also tried to search for a possible answer on Google and YouTube, but didn't find any luck.

All I was expecting was for the array to function normally without causing an excpetion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have? It's much easier for users to copy/paste your code and search around for your error message if it's in text format.